# Ghostscript supported on cloudbees?

Tags: ghostscript, cloudbees

I'd like to use Cloudbees DEV@cloud for continuous integration, but my software requires Ghostscript (i'm using ghost4j), so Ghostscript would need to be installed on the build server. Does anyone know if this is somehow possible?

Comment: As it turned out, Ghostscript is installed on the cloudbees build servers. However I have accepted the answer by @jesse-glick, because I think this approach would work for utilities that are not installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`GhostscriptLibraryLoader.java`](https://github.com/zippy1978/ghost4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/ghost4j/GhostscriptLibraryLoader.java) you would need `libgs.so` in your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, in a 64-bit Linux version (the default architecture for cloud slaves). Currently there is no option to have named system packages preinstalled on the slave—`libgs9` for Ubuntu in this case, but not sure what on the Fedora used for slaves.

However you can get a copy of this file somewhere and deploy it to your [private repository](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Custom+Build+Tools#HPrivaterepository). Then just make sure `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` includes `/private/youraccountid` so it can be found; this might be done at the start of a shell build step, or in general using the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).

Comment: Thanks @jesse-glick, I'll try this and report back.